# \let vs hyperrref

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, hyperref

In the following sample from my custom syllabus class, I am getting a new error since updating my TeXLive 2015 distribution to the most recent release today. The error is `TeX capacity exceeded`.

As far as I can tell the error is the result of an interaction between the `\let`, the `\addcontentsline` command, and the `hyperref` package.
If I define `\term` as a regular `\newcommand`, or if I omit the `\addcontentsline`, then it works with hyperref.

**Why can't I use a `\let` command inside `\addcontentsline` with `hyperref`?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{Week}
\newcommand{\WeekLabel}{Week \theWeek\quad}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Week}{o m}{%                                                                                                                                                          
  \stepcounter{Week}
  \def\ThisWeek{\WeekLabel #2}
  \subsection*{\ThisWeek}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\ThisWeek}%                                                                                                                                                
}

\newcommand{\term}[1]{\emph{#1}} % no error                                                                                                                                                    
%\let\term\emph % produces error with hyperref, why?                                                                                                                                           

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section*{Syllabus}
\tableofcontents

\section{Eighteenth-Century Opera}

\Week[11/09]{Italian \term{opera seria}}

\Week[11/15]{Italian \term{opera buffa}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\NewDocumentCommand`, not `\DeclareDocumentCommand`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title in `\addcontentsline` is also used in the bookmarks. There, the text should be expandable. `\emph` cannot be used for this reason. Also fonts cannot be changed inside bookmarks strings. Package `hyperref` redefines `\emph` inside the bookmarks. But it does not see `\emph` anymore, when `\term` is defined via `\let`.

The easiest solution is using `\newcommand` as in the question, a little optimized:

```
\newcommand{\term}{\emph}
```

Otherwise, `\term` needs to be redefined inside bookmarks:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\term\relax}
```